# Клик через заданное время

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть такая ссылка:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
    onclick="showHide('block_id')">Скрыть/Показать элемент</a>
```

По ней надо через заданное время сделать два клика на JS?

Comment: Зачем два клика?

Comment: Используйте `setTimeout()` и `addEventListener()`.

Comment: setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('fo1').click()
      },3000); Но здесь по id элемента а у этой нет id ?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял вам нужно что-то такое в onclick. Ну или как отметили в комментариях лучше добавлять с addEventListener

```
        setTimeout(function () {
           for(let i=0;i<2;i++)
              showHide('block_id')
        }, TIMEOUT)
```

Но если вам нужно сделать два клика через интервал времени, то возможно вы решаете немного не ту проблему. Может это нужно делать иначе в корне.

Comment: Там еще блок с таким же названием есть и потом строчка for(let i=0;i<2;i++) Выдает ошибку !

Comment: Распишите подробнее. Какая ошибка. Где. Какой блок